# Git Cloned Laravel Project failing at php artisan migrate and php artisan db:seed

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I git cloned a repository for a project written in Laravel/PHP. I was able to get most things running locally and I was able to create the initial migrations folder but I'm stuck at the seeding and table creation point (?). I keep get the following errors:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lara_dev.users' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table `users` add `avatar` varchar(255   
  ) null default 'users/default.png' after `email`, add `role_id` int null after `id`)


In PDOStatement.php line 144:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lara_dev.users' doesn't exist  


In PDOStatement.php line 142:

  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lara_dev.users' doesn't exist
```

*lara_dev is the local database's name. I created it directly in my MySQL local client terminal after git cloning the project, it was NOT created by any commands executed in the terminal.

Also:

The database folder has three folders inside: factories, migrations, and seeds. From what I see and understand, the files inside are configured correctly and the database should be created without issues and without having to edit these files.

I do NOT have a WAMP server, I'm simply using php's built in server through the command 'php artisan serve'.

Solutions I've tried so far that haven't worked:

1. php artisan cache:clear //Clears the cache but that's about it.
2. php artisan migrate:fresh --seed  //Same errors but also drops any tables that were there before.
3. php artisan migrate:refresh --seed // Gives 'nothing to rollback' message.
4. php artisan db:seed //Same errors

I haven't been able to find any solutions here on Stack that work for my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please take into account I am relatively new to PHP, but not to coding, and I've been able to get things running for the most part, I'm just stuck here. If I can provide additional information, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate` command?

Comment: Yes, I did. It gave me the errors above.

Comment: So there's a table being used in a migration that's not created by a previous migration.

Comment: try creating the users table by downlading 
the following file into migrations folder https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniyal Javani gave me the right answer in the comments above. I added that exact file, https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php, to my migrations folder. It created the users table I was missing and then running 'php artisan migrate' worked.

Answer (score 2):

Some migration is failing because it's trying to `alter` the users table, which hasn't been created yet.

Make sure that the migrations are in the correct order, since they get executed in *alphabetical order*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have issues with the order of your migrations. It is trying to alter the table before create it.

***Laravel migrations will contain a timestamp which allows the framework to determine the order of the migrations***

Can you change the alter users table migration file name to `2020_04_24_062125_alter_users_table.php` and try again ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand where your problem is. In Laravel framework we have migrations that defines in `Laravel/database/migrations` folder. They have specefic names.

Their names depend on the date of their creation and are arranged in the same way and executed in the same way.

For ex:

> 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php

and

> 2014_10_12_000001_alter_users_table.php

`create_users_table.php` run in the first place and after that `alter_users_table.php` runs.

**Your Problem:**

You have a part of the code in the migrations that needs to be changed on the users table but your users table not created yet. So you have two ways:

1-change name of `(date_timestamp)_create_users_table.php` In such a way that the create date before the alter migration date

2-change name of migration that has those part of code that alter user table In such a way that the date after the date of the creation of the user table.

At the end run `php artisan migrate:fresh`